# How to make dropdownlist listitems invisible

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two related `DropDownList` controls. Depending on the selection in the parent `DropDownList`, I want to hide some items in the child `DropDownList` in case they were not related to the selected item in the parent `DropDownList`.

I was trying something along the lines of:

```
foreach(ListItem item in ddlChildren.Items)
{
     item.Visible = /* some logic here */
}
```

However the `Visible` property doesn't seem to be available here.

Could someone please suggest how I would go about achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot 'hide' values.  You need to rebind or refill your list from scratch.

Optionally if you just want to remove specific ones you can remove or add but that is usually way more work than just rebuilding the list.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a web application. I used the following to hide specific items within a dropdown list using the enable property on the index of the item I wanted to hide. The item doesn't get grayed out like it would on a windows app. It is actually hidden from view. Please note that my original code was in VB. I've converted a c# version below. Jean-Francois is talking about the same solution above.

this.ddlYourDropDown.Items(3).Enabled == false;

Here is a solution using the value of the specific item...

this.ddlYourDropDown.Items.FindByValue("YourItemValue").Enabled == false

Comment: Best option here

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do something similar by using the Enabled property of items I wanted to hide and setting it to false. When it is set to false, the item is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of scenario, I usually use the cascading drop down extender from the AjaxControlToolkit.

Check it out here: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Project Home Page: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Note that this approach does not alter the *visibility* of list items, but dynamically populates list items based on the results of a Web service method.